# Ubuntu very slow after upgrade

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, updates

I've a Thinkpad s440 with an old Ubuntu 16.04 installation that always worked fine.

Today, just after install SQL Server for Linux and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
shutdown -r now
```

Ubuntu becomes very, very, very slow! The screen animations becomes so slow that you can see it slideUp-Down instead of the normal animations on the boot screen, login and home screens. What can be the possible issues?

Comment: You're saying that just after you tell it to reboot, it starts going slowly while it's rebooting?

Comment: Yes man, exactly like that.

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue running a:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I don't know why, but this solves my problem.

Comment: Solved the slowness issue